# I am trying to run the sever.js file but gives the following warning

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Here is the snipet:

[image]

I am using express 4 .
And here is my code server.js file :

```
// get the required modules 
var express = require('express');
mongoose = require('mongoose');
fs = require('fs');
//define the path for mongoDB
var mongoUri = 'mongodb://localhost/noderest';
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function(){
    //display error
    throw new Error('Failed to connect to the DB @' + mongoUri);
});

//create an instance
var app = express();
//Express 4 --V
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if('development'== env){

    app.use(express.bodyParser());

   /* app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   */
};

require('./models/musician.js');
require('./routes.js')(app);

//listen port 2015
app.listen(2015);
console.log("Listening @ http://localhost:2015");
```

I am totally new in (node.js) .How can I fix fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you should post your script instead of posting a snippet of it. With the part you post, I don't think we can help that much.

Comment: Alright, thanks I am gonna put the code.

Comment: I don't see any warning. The old image of the warning should be fixed by doing what it says.

Comment: Oww I just got it running without any problems.Thanks